# FullCalendar - Set initial time range

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to set the visible time range on the week/day view in FullCalendar?  I would ideally like to show 12 hours (6am to 6pm) in the calendar and then have to use the scroll bar to view outside that range. I've tried these options, but they all seem to come up a bit short:

- minTime/maxTime:  limits the viewable time range, but doesn't allow scrolling outside the range
- firstHour: works great for setting the scroll bar, but when the window is made wider, the aspect ration allows the calendar to get taller and all 24 hours end up showing without a scroll bar.
- contentHeight - height needed to display a defined set of hours is based on window width and aspect ratio, so a fixed value won't work.

Comment: Hi Puck312, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us what you've tried so far? Also, take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "when the window is made wider, the aspect ration _(sic)_ allows the calendar to get taller and all 24 hours end up showing without a scroll bar". What's wrong with that? It's easier for the user. Why force them to scroll if their screen is big enough to show all of it at once? That's just making them do more work (scrolling) when they don't actually need to.

Comment: @JonSaw - The only thing that I have really tried so far was to set contentHeight  equal to 24 times the height of single time slot (1/2 hour slots for 12 hours), but then I realized that it uses an aspect ratio and the height of the time slots is not fixed.  I confirmed the minTime/maxTime stop you from scrolling outside that time range.  Other than that, I have not found a promising method/property to work with in the API documentation.

I'm more than happy to phrase my questions better.  Is there something specific that led you suggest my reviewing "How to Ask"?

Comment: @ADyson - The main reason to limit the time visible time frame is a space issue.  There are things under the calendar, and we don't want it to expand to show 24 hours (when ~95% of the content occurs between 6am and 6pm).  Plus, when the calendar freely resizes to show all 24 hours, it usually causes the user to have to scroll down the page (not to calendar) to see the bottom of the calendar.  Including midnight to 6am puts a lot of blank space at the top of the calendar that the user must potentially scroll past.

Comment: how about setting https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/handleWindowResize/ false?

Comment: @Puck312 It was just to help you increase your chances for an answer. Maybe show us some code samples?  Or show us an example on Codepen or JSFiddle?